# Moving and changing element id's using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on a project to move div elements around and update their id. 
It calls the script and passes the tag's id number. So far it completely works that far. It moves the element up one place and swaps the div id numbers. The only thing is that when I click on the same div to move it again (like moving div#3 to spot#1 by clicking "up" a second time), It doesn't respond to the new div "id" even though it appears to be successfully changed when i inspect it in the browser.

The javascript: just showing the if up

```
enter code here
$("#content_update").on("click", ".rowupdown", function(){
    // button is up or down
    var upordown = $(this).attr('value'); 
    // id number of div from button
    var number = $(this).attr('id');
    // current div can edit id
    var $moveid = $("div#row" + number); 


    var numberint = parseInt(number);
    if (upordown == "up") {
        var s = numberint - 1;
        //number of div to place before and to set id with
        var numberstring = s.toString(); 
        //***ability to select the other div element***
        var $diffrow = "div#row" + numberstring; 
        //** update current div id***
        var $editcurrent = "div#row" + number;
        // puts other div id into this one
        var newid = "row" + numberstring; 
        // puts in this id to the other div
        var editother = "row" + number;
        $($diffrow).before($moveid); // finally moves the current div up one
        $($diffrow).attr("id", editother);
        $($editcurrent).attr("id", newid); //changes id of current div to one before

    }
});
```

the HTML (i have a button that adds new divs and adds 1 to give them a unique id, first click=1 second makes div id = 2 and so on, it doesn't have to do with the question though.)

```
case "row":
        if (!isset($_SESSION["rownumber"])){
        $row = $_SESSION["rownumber"] = 1;
        }
        $row = $_SESSION["rownumber"]++;

        echo " the html
<div class='panel panel-default' id='row".$row."'>
<button class='rowupdown point' id='".$row."' value='up'>up</button>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you bind the event´s to the changed id´s

Comment: oh yeah there is a button with the class "rowupdown" that calls the function